# Downloading a file from a requester pays bucket in amazon s3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to download some replay files from an [API](http://hotsapi.net/docs) that has the files stored on an amazon s3 bucket, with requester pays enabled.

The problem is, I set up my amazon AWS account, created an `AWSAccessKeyId` and `AWSSecretKey`, but I still can't get to download a single file, since I'm getting an `Access denied` response.

I want to automate all this inside a Python script, so I've been trying to do this with the `boto3` package. Also, I installed the Amazon AWS CLI, and set up my access ID and secret key.

The file I've been trying to download (I want to download multiple ones, but for now I'm trying with just one) is this: http://hotsapi.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/18e8b4df-6dad-e1f5-bfc7-48899e6e6a16.StormReplay

From what I've found so far on SO, I've tried something like this:

```
import boto3
import botocore

BUCKET_NAME = 'hotsapi' # replace with your bucket name
KEY = '18e8b4df-6dad-e1f5-bfc7-48899e6e6a16.StormReplay' # replace with your object key

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

try:
    s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY, 'test.StormReplay')
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
        print("The object does not exist.")
    else:
        raise
```

And this:

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.Session().client('s3')
response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='hotsapi',
                                Key='18e8b4df-6dad-e1f5-bfc7-48899e6e6a16.StormReplay', 
                                RequestPayer='requester')
response_content = response['Body'].read()

with open('./B01.StormReplay', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response_content)
```

But I still can't manage to download the file.

Any help is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Access Denied can mean that you do not have permission to access the file. Does the bucket have a Bucket Policy that makes the content public, or are you using a set of access credentials that have access to the object? You could try downloading it with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to test the permissions.

Comment: I tried using the AWS CLI, doing the following:
`aws configure`
`aws s3 ls s3://hotsapi/`
And the response was `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied`

Does that means that I need to request access rights?

Comment: Is it your bucket? Does it have a Bucket Policy? Does your IAM User have any attached policies relating to that bucket, or S3 in general?